# Infinite loop on a flex based container with angled columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

**Problem:**

I've got a container with some angled columns which I want to give an infinite loop animation but I can't handle it

**Question:**

Can be created an effect of infinite loop, even if the columns are angled?

**What I've done so far:**

I have tried to clone the container with elements and put it right before the original one, if the original one is out of the viewport, delete and recreate it after the first clone, and so on.

The thing is that the left of a clone is fixed and on resize it doesn't fit anymore...

**Code snippets:**

HTML:

```
<section id="wrapper" class="portofolio section_st">
    <div id="carousel" class="portfolio-main-container portfolio-animation">
        <div class="portfolio-inner-container">
            <div class="portfolio-item-row">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item1.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item2.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item3.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item-row">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item4.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item5.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item6.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item-row">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item7.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item8.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item9.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item-row">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item1.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item2.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item3.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item-row">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item4.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item5.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item6.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-item-row">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item7.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item1.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-inner">
                        <span class="portfolio-image"><img src="http://www.g3goldentech.ro/inc/images/portfolio/p-item1.png"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
var div = document.getElementById('carousel'),
    clone = div.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "some_id";

var wrapper = document.getElementById('carousel');

var wrapperChildrenLength = wrapper.childElementCount;
var totalWidthOfWrapper = 0;
var totalLeft = 0;
var offsetColumns = 600;

for(var i = 0; i < wrapperChildrenLength; i++){
    totalLeft           += wrapper.children[i].offsetLeft;
    totalWidthOfWrapper += wrapper.children[i].getBoundingClientRect().width;
}

clone.style.left = totalWidthOfWrapper - totalLeft + offsetColumns + "px";

document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(clone);

var moving = false,
    $holder = $('#carousel');

$holder.on('transitionend', function () {
    moving = true;
});

bool = false;
i = 0;

function getPosition() {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('carousel');

    var initial_left = wrapper.children[i].getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var width = wrapper.children[i].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var current_left = $holder.css('left');
    var handled_current_left = current_left.replace("px", "");

    var positive_current_left = (parseFloat(handled_current_left) + initial_left) * -1;

    if(positive_current_left > width){
        bool = true;

        if(bool){
            console.log(wrapper.children);

            $('#carousel').find('.portfolio-item-row').first().remove();

            i++;
            bool = false;
        }
    }

    if (!moving) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(getPosition);
    }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(getPosition);
```

**I've made even a fiddle for ya to see it better:** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zckLumcc/1/)

**One more time the demand:**

I'd like the items to flow to the left with this animation without giving the end animation feeling